# Fortify running a scan spanning several code repositories but generating a single report

Tags: fortify

I am working with a project that consists of several (3 or 4) git repositories. Each repository uses maven to build it.

I need to run fortify against all the repositories, but I want just a single fpr report  containing the results for all the repositories not one per repository.

Is there a recommended way to do this?
Note: there is no overarching pom.xml that  builds the entire application just individual pom.xml files for each repository.

Any tips would be appreciated.
We are using Fortify 16.11 on a Linux server.

Answer (score 1):

Translate all the repositories into the same build id (`-b <build_id>`).

Once they are all translated, run the `-scan` command on that `<build_id>`